# Declare generic method returning enumeration

Tags: scala, generics, enums

I want to implement with Scala analog of the following java code:

```
static <T extends Enum> T getEnumByPrefix(String prefix, Class<T> enumClass) {
    for (T enumValue : enumClass.getEnumConstants()) {
        if (enumValue.name().startsWith(prefix)) {
            return enumValue;
        }
    }
    throw new NoSuchElementException();
}
```

But I can't figure how to declare method for scala.Enumeration.

I tried

```
def enumByPrefix[T <: Enumeration](prefix: String): T.Value = ...
```

but that doesn't compile.

I tried

```
def enumByPrefix[T <: Enumeration.Value](columnLabel: String): T = ...
```

but that doesn't compile too.

Basically I want to use it as follows:

```
object PaymentMethod extends Enumeration {
  val Insurance, Cash = Value
}
...
val paymentMethod: PaymentMethod.Value = enumByPrefix[PaymentMethod]("Insurance")
```

(I used byPrefix just for example, real algorithm will be different).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
scala> def enumByPrefix[T <: Enumeration](prefix: String, enum:T):Option[enum.Value] = 
              enum.values.find(_.toString.startsWith(prefix))

enumByPrefix: [T <: Enumeration](prefix: String, enum: T)Option[enum.Value]
```

Using it with `WeekDay` (defined [here](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Enumeration)) :

```
scala> enumByPrefix("Mon",WeekDay)
res2: Option[WeekDay.Value] = Some(Mon)

scala> enumByPrefix("Mon",WeekDay).map(isWorkingDay)
res3: Option[Boolean] = Some(true)
```